# getting errors while installing tensorflow in windows10 using pip (CPU version)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I have python 3.6 installed on my laptop. I tried to install tensorflow by using pip in anaconda.

but when I run `pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow`.

It is giving me errors as shown below:

```
Collecting tensorflow
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e7/88/417f18ca7eed5ba9bebd51650d04a4af929f96c10a10fbb3302196f8d098/tensorflow-1.9.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
Collecting protobuf>=3.4.0 (from tensorflow)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/75/7a/0dba607e50b97f6a89fa3f96e23bf56922fa59d748238b30507bfe361bbc/protobuf-3.6.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl (1.1MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.1MB 75kB/s
Collecting numpy>=1.13.3 (from tensorflow)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0d/b7/0c804e0bcba6505f8392d042d5e333a5e06f308e019517111fbc7767a0bc/numpy-1.14.5-cp36-none-win_amd64.whl
Collecting absl-py>=0.1.6 (from tensorflow)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/57/8d/6664518f9b6ced0aa41cf50b989740909261d4c212557400c48e5cda0804/absl-py-0.2.2.tar.gz
```

Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Siva\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-glu7to_x\absl-py\
```

I tried to find the path that is causing the error but I couldn't able to get it.

could someone help me resolve this issue?

Comment: Why weren't you able to get to that path? If it's hidden, you can view hidden folders in windows

Comment: yeah...i did but i don't see anything that is starting with pip-install-glu7to_x\absl-py\ in Temp folder

Comment: I'm not an expert on tensorflow. I actually just spent a couple hours installing it onto one of my machines yesterday (win 7, anaconda, python 3.5). I used `pip` instead of `pip3` (as suggested on Tensorflow website)

Answer (score 1):

Your setup tools does not appear to be installed. First download the setuptools.whl form [here](https://pypi.org/project/setuptools/) and install it using pip.

```
pip3 install "path to the whl file"
```

After that try again. If it didn't work,try upgrading the setup tools by,

```
pip3 install --upgrade setuptools
```

and then try again.

If it still does not work just go to [this link](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#tensorflow) and download the tensorflow wheel for your python version, in this case:

> tensorflow‑1.9.0‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl

And install it using

```
pip install "path to the downloaded whl file"
```

Comment: i got this error while trying to upgrade the setup tools using pip File "e:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1590, in load
    mtime = os.stat(path).st_mtime
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'e:\\anaconda\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-27.2.0-py3.6.egg'

Comment: As a workaround, try Installing with anaconda section here, https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows

Comment: @siva_sai_kumar_reddy I have edited the answer, please refer it.

Comment: I tried all the things what you have said but it's giving different errors all the time.I would like to remove python completely from the system and make a fresh installation of anaconda and then try installing tensorflow again

Comment: when you tried last method in the answer, what was the error msg?

Comment: (base) C:\Users\Siva>pip install C:\Users\Siva\Desktop\tensorflow-1.9.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
Processing c:\users\siva\desktop\tensorflow-1.9.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
Collecting gast>=0.2.0 (from tensorflow==1.9.0)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5c/78/ff794fcae2ce8aa6323e789d1f8b3b7765f601e7702726f430e814822b96/gast-0.2.0.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Siva\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vbqg5qf8\gast\

Comment: As I said earlier you have a problem with your setup tools. Clean installation sounds good. :)

Comment: well thank you..but i do have a doubt in doing complete removal of it...is uninstalling python and anaconda gonna remove everything from my system right?

Comment: yes, it should completely remove python(unless you have another python version installed separately which I assume you haven't)

Comment: I removed python and anaconda from my laptop and made a fresh installation of it and tried to download tensorflow but keep getting the same errors.  
Collecting tensorflow
 
Collecting absl-py>=0.1.6 (from tensorflow)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/57/8d/6664518f9b6ced0aa41cf50b989740909261d4c212557400c48e5cda0804/absl-py-0.2.2.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:

   
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Siva\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ccjetvh7\absl-py\   @Nipun Sampath